# Infrared usb adapter not hot pluggable?

Tags: wine, irda

For transferring exercise files from my Polar heart rate monitor i use the software Protrainer 5 with an external infrared usb adapter. Using Wine to run Protrainer 5 and some adjustments mentioned [here](http://forum.polar.fi/showthread.php?t=18421) (using irda-utils) i managed to make it work.

Well, sort of: every time i want to transfer exercise files and the adapter is not plugged in i have to reboot my laptop with the usb adapter plugged in to make it work. Since i have a laptop it unfortunately is no option to just always leave the adapter in.

It seems to me that the usb adapter isn't hot pluggable (which seems odd for a usb device) or there must be another problem.
Polar WebLink (other software to transfer exercise files) experiences the same issue.

**Can anyone help me to fix this problem?**

Infrared usb adapter: Polar IRDA USB adapter

OS: Ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit)

Hardware: Lenovo Thinkpad T500

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer! Restarting irda-utils does the trick. Don't ask me why, but it works...

> sudo /etc/init.d/irda-utils restart

Comment: It's perfectly ok to accept your own answer - you solved the problem, so you deserve the internet points. If you want to automate the process, you can create an udev rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`.